# how to make a single id column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My id column is repeating because user have more than 1 business phone how can I make a single row with single id.

shows..

```
84  NULL    8018xxxx        NULL    NULL    NULL
84  80177xxx    NULL        416-xxx NULL    NULL
84  80177xxx    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
85  (801) 610-xxx   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
86  18005xxx    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I want to result like this..

```
84  80177xxx       8018xxxx     416-xxx NULL    NULL
85  (801) 610-xxx   NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
86  18005xxx        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

my sql

```
Select distinct 
   p.id,
    Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 3 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)          
    End as [Business Phone],
    Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 11 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)
    End as [Mobile Phone],
    Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 13 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)
    End as [Home Phone],
    Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 5 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)
    End as [Assistant],
    Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 5 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)
    End as [Other]
    from People p
    left join [phone] ph on p.id = ph.PeopleId
```

Comment: Do you want to display only 1 of their phone numbers? Also, do you really need varchar(max) for a phone number???

Comment: You need to choose which phone you want to show or have multiple rows.

Comment: I need to display only one business, one home, etc...when they have more than 1 business phone or home phone than i need to create another column saying buisness 2 , home 2 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY clause to aggregate the 'duplicates' into a single row. You might need to wrap the Case Statements with ISNULL(MAX(),'') to deal with NULLS.

```
Select distinct 
   p.id,
    MAX(Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 3 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)          
    End) as [Business Phone],
    MAX(Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 11 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)
    End )as [Mobile Phone],
    MAX(Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 13 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)
    End) as [Home Phone],
    MAX(Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 5 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)
    End) as [Assistant],
    MAX(Case 
        When ph.PhoneLabelId = 5 Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ph.DisplayPhone)
    End) as [Other]
    from People p
    left join [phone] ph on p.id = ph.PeopleId
    GROUP BY p.Id
```

Comment: I did try that and ended up with( phone.PhoneLabelId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause) error

Comment: You will only get that error if you do not wrap your column 'phone.PhoneLabelId' with an aggregate i.e. MAX.

Comment: The example i showed above does already! each MAX() wraps each column! Every column that isn't the thing being grouped needs to be aggregated.